# The constructor is undefined error?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making a login logout module with swipe views 
I extended the class to fragments for the swipe views then I got this error
"The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(Android) is undefined"
this happened after I extended the class to  a fragment it worked before when I was using activity

my whole code

Android.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.learn2crack.library.DatabaseHandler;
    import com.learn2crack.tab.Android;


import java.util.HashMap;

public class Android extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


            View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_frag, container, false);
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            user = db.getUserDetails();

            /**
             * Displays the registration details in Text view
             **/
            final ImageButton logoutbtn = (ImageButton)android.findViewById(R.id.logoutbtn);
            final TextView fname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.fname);
            final TextView lname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.lname);
            final TextView uname = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.uname);
            final TextView email = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.email);
            final TextView created_at = (TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.regat);
            fname.setText(user.get("fname"));
            lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
            uname.setText(user.get("uname"));
            email.setText(user.get("email"));
            created_at.setText(user.get("created_at"));


            logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
                }
                });
            return android;}

                public void logout(){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.this);

                alertDialog.setTitle("Logout"); // Sets title for your alertbox

                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Logout ?"); // Message to be displayed on alertbox



                /* When positive (yes/ok) is clicked */
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent login = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    getActivity().finish();

                }
                });

                /* When negative (No/cancel) button is clicked*/
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                }
}
```

Comment: use `Android.this.getActivity());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent class (Function) has a constructor your child class also needs to have one, otherwise use `Android.this.getActivity());` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragments` don't extend from `Context`, and you need to provide it a `Context` parameter. So instead of `Android.this`, use `Android.this.getActivity()`.